# Protect against large current spikes while not reducing consistent current input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fen81M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a fairly straight forward transimpedence amplifier to convert collected current from ions into a voltage.

My biggest problem is the cup has to be placed far away from the ionization source. Because (And this has happened quite a few times) even a very brief arc from the ionization source onto the cup is a huge surge in current and just fries the op amp.

So this has the dual problem of frying a bunch of my op amps and causing me to place the faraday cup so far away from the source that even with such an enormous gain, I'm still experiencing an 100mV output at most.

What are potential methods I may use to protect my op amp from these large current spikes while maintaining the constant current I expect to be coming from the ions?

Answer (score 1):

I would place back to back switched Zener diodes on the input of your circuit. This is cutting the input spikes (positive and negative) to a reasonable level without impacting the signal you want to measure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ZWZf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>